# OnPostExecute method in a Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio

does somebody know how can I deal with the mistake in OnPostExecute method when I want to findViewById. I know that it is not possible to use findViewById in Fragments, but can't find a solution in this method

public class TelephoneFragment extends Fragment {

```
ListView listview;
ListViewAdapter adapter;

public TelephoneFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View vs=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    new JsoupListView().execute();
    return vs;


}
private class JsoupListView extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android Jsoup ListView Tutorial");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

   ....
```

...
...

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
        listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), arraylist);
        // Set the adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: The `context` is already within the fragment. hint: `getActivity()`

Comment: if you want to find a view within what you created in `onCreateView`, you can use `getView().findViewById(R.id.listview);`

Answer (score 0):

You cant use findViewById in fragment where you want. You need to have root view from onCreateView or onViewCreated methods and then you can find some views on it. 
You can find needed views in onCreateView, keep reference to them in your fragment and then you can use them in your onPostExecute.